# Tensorboard reported accuracy does not match my own calculations

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, accuracy

I'm using Google's AI Platform to train an image classifier with Tensorflow (resnet-50 model). I have only two classes. Training set is something like 4K images in size and validation set 1K images. After 20000 steps training is finished and Tensorboard reports top-1 accuracy above 80% (by the way I don't know how it's possible to have smoothed curve consistently below the non smoothed one):

[image]

When I try to do "manually" my own calculation (on the same validation set), I get much lower figures though (something like 60-65%). I did my own calculations after having saved the model locally. I've validated my method by deploying my model on AI Platform too (prediction results are stricly the same that those that I get locally).

Where is my error? Could it be that I have to preprocess my images before sending them to predict API? (something that would be done without my knowledge in the evaluation part while training).

EDIT: the training job that I submit to AI Platform includes the num_eval_images parameter. It is set to 0 since "If it is 0, all the images in validation_data_path will be used for evaluation" (see https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/image-classification-start#gcloud)

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code?